# The standard Namespace problem

Tags: c++

Hii ,

I am relatively new to programming C++ . I do know that the functions cout , cin  etc... are defined in the standard name space . But we also include iostream  header file for running the program .

So , is it like

```
 namespace std
   {

     declaration of cout 

     declaration of cin 

     ..... some other declarations etc....

   }
```

and theior actual implementations inside istream and ostream ... ????

Or , is it the other way round ...??? like ....

```
namespace std 
   {
     complete definition of cout 
     complete definition of cin  
     .........

   }
```

and their signatures are just placed in the iostream file  like ...

```
iostream file 
  {
    std :: cout 
    std :: cin 
    .....

  }
```

Please provide any examples or links that you might think will help me understand better

Comment: It is implementation defined. But the classes (std::basic_stream) are declared inside the namespace std, as are the objects (std::cin,std::cout). Weather there is a definition of the classes/objects in the header file is implementation defined.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I do know that the functions cout ,
>   cin etc... are defined in the standard
>   name space.

These are not really functions, but global instances of `basic_ostream` and `basic_istream`.

> But we also include iostream header file for running the program.

You rather include headers so you can compile your source (the compiler needs to declarations etc).

The rest of the question is rather fuzzy. How the standard library is implemented is pretty much up to the implementation. The standard requires that if you include `iostream`, you will get the declarations of the following globals:

```
namespace std {
  extern istream cin;
  extern ostream cout;
  extern ostream cerr;
  extern ostream clog;

  extern wistream wcin;
  extern wostream wcout;
  extern wostream wcerr;
  extern wostream wclog;
}
```

Comment: @Billy: without `extern` these would be definitions rather than declarations, and you don't want definitions of external objects in a header.

Comment: @Bens: So , when we use cout , cin  we are using basic_ostream , basic_istream objects ... ? And basic_istream and basic_ostream handle the facilities of o/p and i/p .. ???

Comment: @Mike: Well, I suppose you could make the standard streams have internal members which were extern, and the other things to simply have internal linkage, but what you say makes a lot more sense :)

Answer (score 2):

The standard really doesn't say. It's entirely possible for the implementer to do it as a header-only library, but it's much more likely for them to just put the declarations in headers and put the implementations in the CRT.

EDIT: However, the definitions for `cin`, `cout`, etc need to be `extern` and defined in some sort of library. (See UncleBens' answer)

Answer (score 1):

`cin` and `cout` are not simple variables - with `cerr` they are streams registered by default for every application using iostream. you can't use them without including that header.

Answer (score 1):

To use `cin` and `cout` you really only have to know that they're in the `std` namespace and that you need to include `iostream` to use them.

To give you an idea how it might be implemented, the definition of class `std::ostream` could be in the header `ostream`, which is included by `iostream`. Also in the header `ostream`, `std::cout` could be defined as a reference to an `std::ostream`.